# NPM caret doesn't bring in newest minor version

Tags: javascript, npm

In my package.json one of my dependencies is...
"@packageXXX": "^0.7.0",

When I do a "npm outdated" I see...
@packageXXX   current: 0.7.0       wanted: 0.7.0        latest: 0.8.0

When I do "npm i"
it doesn't install the latest minor version "0.8.0"

My understand is having the caret there is suppose to update to the latest minor version, but it doesn't. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the case with 0.x.x since a leading zero indicates that the package isn't into a "stable" version yet. Until your package hits 1.x.x you'll need to do these updates manually (and be careful...your package isn't stable yet, meaning breaking changes can occur!).

https://semver.org/

> Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything may
>   change at any time. The public API should not be considered stable.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact thing where I depend on "^1.0.1" and 1.0.2 is available, yet it only installs 1.0.1... how do you explain that?

Comment: @Michael your package manager is making a mistake (or you are). If you're not using Yarn, I'd highly recommend it.

Comment: Its old comment, but for the future readers following might be issue
@Michael I think the newer package version peer dependencies are not matching whats installed in your project dependencies , to find out that just try to npm install <package> it will give ERESOLVE error

Answer (score 2):

As per [nodejs documentation](https://nodejs.dev/learn/semantic-versioning-using-npm), package `^0.7.0` -> will not be updated to `0.8.0` by `npm update`

> ^: It will only do updates that do not change the leftmost non-zero number. If you write ^0.13.0, when running npm update, it can update to 0.13.1, 0.13.2, and so on, but not to 0.14.0 or above. If you write ^1.13.0, when running npm update, it can update to 1.13.1, 1.14.0 and so on, but will not update to 2.0.0 or above.