# npm package not updating minor versions

Tags: npm

I'm trying to figure out why rollup is not updating. in my package file I have:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^0.62.0",
}
```

Running `npm outdated` shows:

```
package       Current    Wanted    Latest
rollup        0.62.0     0.62.0    0.67.1
```

If the carat indicates that everything but major versions can be updated, and in this specific case the latest version is only a minor version, why wouldn't it update with `npm update rollup`?

I realise that the Wanted is preventing the update, but why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM caret doesn't bring in newest minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637066/npm-caret-doesnt-bring-in-newest-minor-version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004,

[Carets] Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple. In other words, this allows patch and minor updates for versions 1.0.0 and above, patch updates for versions 0.X >=0.1.0, and no updates for versions 0.0.X.

If you know that you want the latest versions `0.67.1`, you could specify your dependency as

```
"devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "0.x",
}
```