# npm not installing latest version of my package

Tags: npm, npm-install, azure-artifacts

I have created my own npm feed in Azure Artifacts.  I can publish my package and use it in my applications.

In my applications, the package is referenced like this in the package.json

```
`"@op/breeze-helpers": "^0.1.5"`
```

If I now publish version 0.1.6 of my package, delete my package from node_modules and run `npm i` , npm installs version 0.1.5 again !

I even tried  `npm i --cache c:/tmp/empty-cache` to make sure it was not getting the package from cache, but it ends up the same. npm keeps installing version 0.1.5

what am doing wrong, I thought with the caret, the next minor should be downloaded when running `npm i`  ?

Comment: Ok, I made some progress. It appears this is because of the  `package-lock.json` file preventing the upgrade.  If I remove this file, my package is upgraded to `0.1.7`.  However I also have a version `0.2.0` in my feed. How come the package was not upgraded to `0.2.0` ?  And how do I skip using this file for packages in my own feed ? I want to be on latest version always.

Comment: I think this an accurate answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637066/npm-caret-doesnt-bring-in-newest-minor-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package-lock.json sets your currently installed version of each package in stone, and npm will use those exact versions when running npm install.

So it will download the package versions from the package-lock.json file.

> I want to be on latest version always.

You could try to set the `"*"` as the dependency package version.

For example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "*",
    "@types/jquery": "*",
    "bootstrap": "*"

  }
```

Then it will always download the latest version of the target packages.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I will mark this as the answer. However i changed my mind and I don't think it's a good idea to force latest minor version. Version should be locked by package-lock.json and upgraded manually by developper, as indicated in npm documentation. This guarantees same behavior across different server bulds and is the way to go when using different deployment environments.